# img tag is getting value of src after input but image is not getting displayed

Tags: javascript, html, css

img tag is getting value of **src** after giving image as an input but still image is not getting displayed.

By using `previewimage.setAttribute("src", this.result);` value of src is given to the img tag.

```js
const inpfile = document.getElementById("inpfile");
        const previewcontainer = document.getElementById("imagepreview");
        const previewimage = previewcontainer.querySelector(".image-preview__image");
        const previewdefaulttext = previewcontainer.querySelector(".image-preview__default-text");
        inpfile.addEventListener("change", function () {
            const file = this.files[0];
            if (file) {
                const reader = new FileReader();


                previewdefaulttext.style, display = "none";
                previewimage.style, display = "block";


                reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
                    previewimage.setAttribute("src", this.result);
                });

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            } else {
                previewdefaulttext.style, display = null;
                previewimage.style, display = null;
                previewimage.setAttribute("src", "");
            }
        });
```

```css
image-preview {
            width: 300px;
            min-height: 100px;
            border: 2px solid #dddddd;
            margin-top: 15px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #cccccc;
        }

        .image-preview__image {
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<input type="file" name="inpfile" id="inpfile">
    <div class="image-preview" id="imagepreview">
        <img src="" alt="image preview" class="image-preview__image">
        <span class="image-preview__default-text">image preview</span>
    </div>
```

What mistake I did?
Thank You So Much in advance.

Comment: The image is still on `display:none`

Answer (score 0):

Replace

`previewimage.style, display = "block"`

with

`previewimage.style.display = "block"`

Answer (score 0):

Try this you just have to replace the "," with "." in

```
previewimage.style.display
```

```js
const inpfile = document.getElementById("inpfile");
        const previewcontainer = document.getElementById("imagepreview");
        const previewimage = previewcontainer.querySelector(".image-preview__image");
        const previewdefaulttext = previewcontainer.querySelector(".image-preview__default-text");
        inpfile.addEventListener("change", function () {
            const file = this.files[0];
            if (file) {
                const reader = new FileReader();


                previewdefaulttext.style.display = "none";
                previewimage.style.display = "block";


                reader.addEventListener("load", function () {
                    previewimage.setAttribute("src", this.result);
                });

                reader.readAsDataURL(file);
            } else {
                previewdefaulttext.style, display = null;
                previewimage.style.display = null;
                previewimage.setAttribute("src", "");
            }
        });
```

```css
image-preview {
            width: 300px;
            min-height: 100px;
            border: 2px solid #dddddd;
            margin-top: 15px;
            display: flex;
            align-items: center;
            justify-content: center;
            font-weight: bold;
            color: #cccccc;
        }

        .image-preview__image {
            display: none;
            width: 100%;
        }
```

```html
<input type="file" name="inpfile" id="inpfile">
    <div class="image-preview" id="imagepreview">
        <img src="" alt="image preview" class="image-preview__image">
        <span class="image-preview__default-text">image preview</span>
    </div>
```

Comment: Np abishek kambie:)